# Compressing images during uploads in Java

Tags: java, spring, graphics2d, jai

In my `Java Spring MVC Web Application`, I have options to upload images of any size. Currently I have an API that reduces the size of any uploaded image that is above a specified width. I use the following code for that:

```
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.image.renderable.ParameterBlock;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.media.jai.JAI;
import javax.media.jai.PlanarImage;
import javax.media.jai.RenderedOp;

public class ImageRescale 
{
    private static RenderingHints hints;

    static 
    {
        hints = new RenderingHints(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BICUBIC);
        hints.put(RenderingHints.KEY_COLOR_RENDERING,RenderingHints.VALUE_COLOR_RENDER_QUALITY);
        hints.put(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);

        /*
         * this block is to silence the warning that we're not using JAI
         * native acceleration but are using the pure java implementation.
         */
        Properties p = new Properties(System.getProperties());
        p.put("com.sun.media.jai.disableMediaLib", "true");
        System.setProperties(p);
    }  


    public static byte[] getScaledInstance(byte[] image, int maxWidth) 
    {
        InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(image);
        BufferedImage img = null;
        try 
        {
            img = ImageIO.read(in);

        double scale = (double) maxWidth / img.getWidth();
        if ( scale > 1.0d ) 
        {
            return image;
        } 
        else if (scale > 0.5d && scale < 1.0d) 
        {
            return getByteArray(getScaledDownByGraphics(img, scale));
        } 
        else if (scale <= 0.5d) 
        {
            return getByteArray(getScaledDownByJAI(img, scale));
        }
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return image;
    }

    public static byte[] getByteArray(BufferedImage img)
    {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        byte[] imageInByte = null;
        try 
        {
            ImageIO.write( img, "jpg", baos );
            baos.flush();
            imageInByte = baos.toByteArray();
            baos.close();
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return imageInByte;
    }

    /**
     * See http://www.digitalsanctuary.com/tech-blog/java/how-to-resize-uploaded-images-using-java-better-way.html
     * This instance seems to produce quality images ONLY when you are
     * scaling down to something less than 50% of the original size.
     * @param img
     * @param scale
     * @return the scaled image
     */
    private static BufferedImage getScaledDownByJAI(BufferedImage img, double scale) 
    {
        if(scale > 1.0d) 
        {
            throw new RuntimeException("Can't scale according to " + scale + " : This method only scales down.");
        }
        PlanarImage originalImage = PlanarImage.wrapRenderedImage(img);
        // now resize the image
        ParameterBlock paramBlock = new ParameterBlock();
        paramBlock.addSource(originalImage); // The source image
        paramBlock.add(scale); // The xScale
        paramBlock.add(scale); // The yScale
        paramBlock.add(0.0); // The x translation
        paramBlock.add(0.0); // The y translation
        RenderedOp resizedImage = JAI.create("SubsampleAverage", paramBlock, hints);
        return resizedImage.getAsBufferedImage();      
    }

    /**
     * This method produces high quality images when target scale is greater
     * than 50% of the original.
     * @param img
     * @param scale
     * @return the scaled image
     */
    private static BufferedImage getScaledDownByGraphics(BufferedImage img, double scale) 
    {
        final float scaleFactor = 0.8f;

                BufferedImage ret = (BufferedImage)img;
                int w = img.getWidth();
                int h = img.getHeight();

                int targetWidth = (int)(img.getWidth() * scale);
                int targetHeight = (int)(img.getHeight() * scale);

                int loopCount = 0;
                int maxLoopCount = 20;
                BufferedImage tmp;
                do {
                        if (w > targetWidth) {
                                w *= scaleFactor;
                                if (w < targetWidth) {
                                        w = targetWidth;
                                }
                        }
                        if (h > targetHeight) {
                                h *= scaleFactor;
                                if (h < targetHeight) {
                                        h = targetHeight;
                                }
                        }
                        tmp = new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
                        Graphics2D g2 = tmp.createGraphics();

                        g2.addRenderingHints(hints);
                        g2.drawImage(ret, 0, 0, w, h, null);
                        g2.dispose();

                        ret = tmp;
                        if(++loopCount > maxLoopCount) {
                                throw new RuntimeException("Hit maximum loop count " + maxLoopCount);
                        }
                } while (w != targetWidth || h != targetHeight);
                return ret;    
    }
}
```

But what I want now is an API that compresses all uploaded images and bring down its resolution to around `72 dpi` which I believe is the web standard for images. Is there any way I can achieve this.

Comment: Do you mean "resize" when you write "compress"? You can do that, when you know how large the image should be measured in mm or inches or if you know the dpi of the image. This information can either be embedded in metadata in the image file or it needs to be passed in separately.

Comment: I want all images to have a resolution of around 72dpi. Without reducing its width and height.

Answer (score 1):

Could you check if this would help you?

```
    /**
 *
 * @param bi image
 * @param mimeType type
 * @param quality quality
 * @return compressed image
 * @throws IOException on error
 */
private static BufferedImage compressImage(BufferedImage bi, String mimeType
        , float quality) throws IOException {
    // converting buffered image to byte array

    // do not compress GIFs
    if (mimeType.equalsIgnoreCase("image/gif")) {
        return bi;
    }

    ImageWriter writer = ImageIO.getImageWritersByMIMEType(mimeType).next();
    ImageWriteParam iwp = writer.getDefaultWriteParam();

    if (!mimeType.equalsIgnoreCase("image/png") && !mimeType.equalsIgnoreCase("image/bmp")) {
        iwp.setCompressionMode(ImageWriteParam.MODE_EXPLICIT);
        iwp.setCompressionQuality(quality);
    }

    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    BufferedOutputStream bos = new java.io.BufferedOutputStream(baos);
    ImageOutputStream ios = ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(bos);
    writer.setOutput(ios);

    IIOImage optimizedImage = new IIOImage(bi, null, null);
    writer.write(null, optimizedImage, iwp);
    writer.dispose();
    baos.flush();

    ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray());
    return ImageIO.read(in);
}
```